# facebook messenger an array of generic templates

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, messenger

I have noticed we have quick_reply and to send multiple of them, you can use quick_replies. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/send-api-reference/quick-replies#quick_reply

How do I send multiple generic template attachments in one message. This is to enable a user scroll through and choose one of the templates.

I have seen one implemented by the Guardian bot. https://www.messenger.com/t/10513336322

Answer (score 0):

You attach an array of elements as seen here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/send-api-reference/generic-template

Comment: Thank you. I was actually thinking each had to be an attachment object, didn't consider the array of elements. Fixed and working now